# Is there any certain canon about the Ogre Empire?

Tags: world-of-warcraft

With the new raids and us having to kill the Imperator, and me not being able to find any further information about this Ogre Empire (not mention of such thing in any of the WoW archive novels) I would like to know when this creatures became an empire. It seems obvious they were in this new timeline an empire long before Garrosh arrived, but it was already falling? or started falling with the attacks of the Iron Horde?

When did it come to be an empire when in our timeline they're no more than tribes of brutish creatures. Or were they an empire in our timeline, but one that was extinct long before the draenei arrived in Oshu'gun?

Answer (score 3):

According to [wowiki](http://www.wowwiki.com/Ogre):

> Originally from Draenor, ogres were one of the last races of
>   Draenor's giants. Some orc scholars believe the ogres were once
>   intelligent and the dominant species of Draenor before the orcs rose
>   to power. Orcs and ogres were enemies for generations until the rise
>   of the horde. The warlock Gul'dan decided the orcs required the brute
>   strength of the ogres in their war against the draenei. The ogres
>   joined the horde in exchange for freedom from the tyranny of the Gronn
>   and for providing food and weapons. Any ogres who stayed loyal to the
>   gronn were ruthlessly conquered. Soon the ogres were broken, the race
>   either forced into exile or enslaved and used in experiments. To this
>   day, most ogres hate orcs with a passion, remembering the wars they
>   fought against each other

[This information is cited as from the novel *"Rise of The Horde"* and the *"Horde Players Guide"* for the RPG]

So it sounds like they once had an empire in the Original timeline, but were conquered by the Horde prior to the invasion of Azeroth.

In the Warlords of Draenor timeline, this seems to be exactly what is happening as well. The ogres have the remains of an empire which the Iron Horde are slowly conquering or allying with.